# template operator << getting round

Tags: c++, templates, operators, operator-overloading

In library code I have:

```
class VeryStrictClass
{
public:
    template<typename UNKNOWN_TYPE>
    VeryStrictClass& operator<<(const UNKNOWN_TYPE & value) {
        struct can_not_format_unknown_type {};
        can_not_format_unknown_type error = value;
    }
};
```

no way to reimplement it.

This forbids to declare functions like

```
template <typename MsgType>
/*check toString existance*/
VeryStrictClass& operator << (VeryStrictClass& o, const MsgType* msg) 
{
  BOOST_ASSERT(msg != NULL);
  return o << msg->toString();
}
```

**where toString() isn't virtual.**

I have lots of similar classes to be put into VeryStrictClass. Is there any way to get round this constraint?

Comment: "similar" to what? "put into" how? What constraint?

Comment: all of them have toString() method. put into using operator <<. toString() must not be virtual

Answer (score 1):

You could use template specialization for you own types of messages.

```
class foo {};

class bar : public foo {}

template <>
VeryStrictClass& VeryStrictClass::operator<< <foo> (const foo & bar) {
    // something something
    return *this;
}

VeryStrictClass v;
bar* b = new bar;
foo* f = new foo;
v << *foo << *((foo*)bar);
```

not sure if this works though

EdiT: added some polymorphism

Edit: otherwise you can not.

Comment: but is is the same as if I overloaded the function for each type. And exactly what I want to avoid :)

Comment: @D_E with the edits you should be able to work out something in your favor using polymorphism.

Comment: Unfortunately these classes are used as POD. I cant just add a parent class and virtual function.

Comment: I did: 'where toString() isn't virtual.'